# TYPO3 Ajax in Backend Extension

Tags: ajax, typo3, backend

I have been looking for a way to use some AJAX feature in a TYPO3 extension.

I want to select 2 fields in my extension "cars" - brands and models (models are linked to cars in database):

table brands:

- uid
- label

table models:

- uid
- label
- brand (uid from brand table)

In the backend, when I create a new "car", first I choose a brand. Then I want the models fields to automatically update and show a list with all the models of this selected brand

I found the [doc](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/4.2.0/view/3/9/) but I don't know how to deal with the client side.  In which file do I have to add the following lines, and where does the JavaScript go:

```
$this->doc->loadJavascriptLib('contrib/prototype/prototype.js');
$this->doc->loadJavascriptLib('js/common.js');
```

Comment: Which TYPO3 Version are you using? Is this a Backend Module or Frontend Plugin? Maybe there is jQuery in Fronend?

Comment: typo3 4.7.  its a frontend plugin (with kickstarter) but i want to use ajax in the backend side of this plugin

Answer (score 3):

First of all.. The doc you've been refering isn't the right path. Please see this [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InsideTypo3Reference/8.7/CoreArchitecture/Backend/Routing/Index.html)

Following are the basic steps to be followed in your context.

**1) Register an ajax call in your ext_tables.php**

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::registerAjaxHandler (
   'controllername::function_name',
   'PITS\\PitsDownloadLogin\\Controller\\controllername->function_name'
);
```

above mentioned 'function_name' lying inside 'controller' defines the logic to be executed in your ajax call.

**2) Define your ajax call**  <- This part is the client side you were talking about

Definitely you do have a script file, I mean JS file where functions to be triggered onclick is written. In your case define a js function in 'onChange' of the first bar where brand is chosen. Define ajax inside this function.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: TYPO3.settings.ajaxUrls['controllername::function_name'],
data: {
    "page" : page,
    "limit": limit,
},
```

Now the following parameters will be received in your 'function_name' in the respective controller.
Process it as you wish.

**3) Controller stubs**

```
/**
 * Renders the table as pagination occurs
 *
 * @param array $params Array of parameters from the AJAX interface, currently unused
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\AjaxRequestHandler $ajaxObj Object of type AjaxRequestHandler
 * @return void
 */
public function function_name($params = array(), \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Http\AjaxRequestHandler &$ajaxObj = NULL) {     

    $limit = GeneralUtility::_GP('limit');
    $page = GeneralUtility::_GP('page');
         **** Code Processing ***
    $result = result of whole processing
    $ajaxObj->addContent('success', $result); // In JS 'success' is the final result passed from here
    $ajaxObj->setContentFormat('json');       // Writing back as JSON array
}
```

In your JS file you can decide the rest through,

```
success: function (success) {
    console.log(success);
},
error: function (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

*I hope you are deviated to the right direction.. Happy coding mate. !*

> This answer is now deprecated. TYPO3 no more supports this functionality. Please refer to AjaxRoutes instead. Which is a much easier method.

Comment: documentation link is leading to 404

Comment: Yes. So edited the answer and added latest method hint with documentation link. Thanks for the notification @Aswathy S.